# PC crashes randomly after BIOS-Reset

Tags: power-supply, crash, gpu

my PC crashes randomly since 3 weeks - just turns off, no shutdown.

- no warnings, no errors
- BlueScreenView doesn't show anything (0 errors)
- no sound-warning

  Event-ID: 6008
  System was shut down unexpectedly

What I did **after** this issue occured:

- cleaned the GPU-Fan
- cleaned the CPU-Fan
- increased the GPU-Fan-Speed from 33% to 50% standard
- monitored the temp of GPU/CPU via several tools - no bad values.
- ran a 30minutes Test via "HeavyLoad" - no errors, no shutdown.

**Here are my speccs**:

MSI-7350
IntelCore 2duo, E6750 @ 2.66GHz
4GB RAM
nVidia 560 GTX
Win7 Pro 64bit

I hope you can help me, since I'm really frustrated :(

Comment: read all steps from scenario 3 of this KB and try it: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of problems that are about the worst for diagnosing, because so many things can be going on and we don't really know much about what's happening under the hood.

That said, there are two components that are likely culprits when the system starts shutting down randomly, all temperature readings indicate nothing out of the ordinary and all fans (including the case fans) are working.

Random shutdowns can be the result of **power supply** problems. This is also relatively easy to check, and a fairly cheap fix (a simple power supply isn't that expensive). I suggest that you start out by confirming that all cable connections (both power and data) are secure; I would recommend that you unplug and firmly reseat them, one by one. If you can scrounge (or have) a spare, *known good,* PSU to test with, I would suggest installing that one and seeing if it helps. If it helps, then your problems are likely PSU-related, and you should just go out and buy a new PSU rated for the load your system puts on it. There are ATX power supply testers available relatively cheaply; especially if you have a high-end PSU, one such might not be a bad investment before you go out and buy a new PSU.

It could also [possibly be the **motherboard**](https://superuser.com/a/440379/53590) that is acting up. Unfortunately, they don't last forever, and I don't know a good way to actually *test* for this possibility. If that's the case, unfortunately you may be in the market for a new motherboard, which will likely also mean a new CPU and possibly RAM.