# Freeze during Battlefield 3 - Probable Hardware issue?

Tags: windows-7, freeze

my friend's notebook frequently freezes during BF3 sessions since ~1 1/2 months. It runs Win764Bit and he already reinstalled windows during the process, it didn't help. So we guess it might probably be a hardware issue. Now the question - which part of the hardware could effect a total freeze of the system WITHOUT getting a bluescreen? Or are there any known software issues he could also try? The hardware specs are:

Acer 7745G
Intel i7 720QM
AMD Mobility 5850HD - Running Catalyst 11.6 now btw. (all drivers tested from 11.2 to 12.6 though)
4GB Ram 1.333MHz

Oh and yeah, he just added that it crashes playing Diablo3 from time to time, too.

Please help :)

Comment: [this](http://superuser.com/q/437005/82812) SuperUser question has more details on hardware troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

My bet would be a graphics card issue, and/or power supply. You should be able to run a stress test for the graphics that will tell you if that is the problem (you can use the free version of [Futuremark](http://www.futuremark.com/))

Comment: Neither Unigine Heaven nor 3DMark could reproduce the error...we're still on it...