# Notebook won't boot

Tags: laptop, boot

I've got a HP Pavilion dv3 notebook and it won't boot.

When I hit the Power button, the screen stays black for about 10 seconds (when I'm supposed to see the HP screen) and it flashes. The screen becomes white for half-second, then it becomes black again for a few seconds and becomes white for half-second, etc.

The Caps Lock and Num Lock LEDs flashe once, then after 3-4 seconds, flashes once again and so on.

- I am unable to go in the BIOS, unable to go in Windows, unable to boot on a live-CD.
- The fan starts to spin, then stops after 5 seconds.
- I tried to boot without hard drive, without RAM and without DVD drive, wihout success.
- I tried with and without battery, without success.
- I succeeded to boot the computer with BIOS acces or Windows (5-6 times out of hundred tries), but now, I am neither able to boot again, nor to go in the BIOS.

What can I do to boot the computer?

**Edit:**
I found a video on Youtube of someone who had the same problem.
Here is the link:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SziIr34Md0g
The problem would be the video card.
The guy repaired it by reflowing it.
Do you think it is true?
Do you know a similar case where such a technique worked?

Comment: You've tried everything I would have tried... How's that for help?  ....  Have you tried no battery and a different power supply?

Comment: Have you pulled the heat pipe assembly off the processor, making sure that it is not only sitting properly, but not bent in the slightest?  It wouldn't be the first time that the heat pipe/heat sink assembly was sitting against the plastic chassis in such a way as not to be seated properly, putting incorrect or inconsistent pressure on the processor, etc.  At any rate, check how the processor is seated in the socket as well.

Comment: Stupid question: have you plugged in another screen and tested if that's the problem at all?

Comment: Yes I tried with another screen. I will verify the heat sink.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Diagnose a Pre-Operating System Load or Hardware Issue](http://superuser.com/questions/437005/how-to-diagnose-a-pre-operating-system-load-or-hardware-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, I had to reflow the video chip using a heat gun, as shown in the video link from my first post.

Answer (score 1):

You said you tried booting without RAM. How many DIMMs were there? If more than one, try booting with one and then the other. I had a laptop that acted similarly, and it turned out to be a bad stick of RAM that caused the problem.

Comment: I tried that without any success.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no way 
I have worked at a computer store a while and most of the times Hp laptops come in with the same problem and the end result is that the motherboard is fried. 
If you want it to boot you will need to buy another motherboard

Tip :  Some Hp Dv series have motherboard flaws.

Comment: How to be sure the motherboard is the problem? I mean, if the motherboard blink LEDs, doesn't this mean the motherboard works?

Comment: @antoyo No there are different circuits in the motherboard there can be problems in  certain areas and not in the other areas. I have seen many hp laptops with this problem. When a motherboard is fried it doesn't mean the whole motherboard it means a part of it. So there will be some sort of activity still happening.