# No signal to monitor

Tags: display

I've just recently decided to start reusing my PC (The monitor is a HP w2007v, the tower was hand built).

The problem I have is although the tower seems to fire up fine, making all the right noises and beeps etc, when the monitor lights up, it instantly says on the screen "monitor is going into sleep mode".

I've tried a different monitor I know definitely works and it's the same thing.  I've tried another cable (the blue jobby with the screws on either side) and still the same.

Is there anything I can do to solve this?

I've no real recent experience with computers, but I'm a bit of a 'have a go guy'.

Comment: [How to Diagnose a Pre-Operating System Load or Hardware Issue](http://superuser.com/q/437005)

Comment: Does the computer have onboard video or a discrete video card in one of the slots?

Comment: The blue jobby with screws - VGA cable.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider would be your monitor settings: Are they set to the proper input signal?

Does your PC use integrated graphics, or does it have a graphics card?
(Chances are, if your PC was built out-of-factory, you could have a graphics card, allowing you more than one port to plug a display cable into)

If you do have a graphics card installed, that will disable the integrated graphics, unless you set it otherwise in Device Manager. So make sure you are plugging your cable into the correct port.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, it only has 1 port for the monitor to connect to the tower, when I last used this pc,there was no issues with it and as far as I can see I have set it up the same as before, so I would have thought the settings would be the same. As for the graphics card, I don't think it is intergrated, I seem to remember the chap who made it said he could upgrade It if I found it wasn't doing The job..I have to say, I am no computer genius, the reason why I had this made is at the time I was a big gamer and the off the shelf towers weren't upto the job

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, it seems you do indeed have a graphics card.

Comment: Time to open up your PC. (Its not as scary as it sounds) The first thing I would check would be to see if the card itself became unseated from the motherboard. It may not be the case, but stranger things have happened. Once you've confirmed that, verify that you have power to the card (Perhaps a power cable came loose) and then turn your PC on. Most graphics cards need extra power from the PSU to work properly, it's possible that a cable came loose.